# Update Entity with a new field in a controller - Symfony 6

Tags: php, symfony, controller, symfony5, symfony6

I'm new in Symfony, and I am trying to calculate the average of the customer reviews at the controller level.

I did a dump in the foreach shown below, where I have the entity as I want, but in the return of the `postman` the field I added does not exist in my object.

> nb: I don't have this field in my user table

**My controller:**

```
public function __invoke(UserRepository $rep, Request $request , EntityManagerInterface $em)

{

    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

    $dataUser = $rep->findUsersData();
    $Reviews = $rep->findUsersReviews($user->getId());
    $countReviews = count($Reviews);
    $starsValues = 0;
    foreach($Reviews as $review){
        //dump($review);
        $starsValues += $review['stars'];
    }
    $reviewsuservalue = $starsValues / $countReviews;

    foreach($dataUser as $key => $userForeach){
        if($userForeach->getId() == $user->getId()){
            $userForeach->setReviewsuservalue($reviewsuservalue);
            //dump($dataUser[$key]->getReviewsuservalue());
            $em->persist($userForeach);
            $em->flush();
            //dump($em->flush());
        }
    }


    return $this->json($dataUser);

}
```

and I add this in **my entity:**

```
private $reviewsuservalue;
```

and this is **my getter & setter in the mentioned entity**

```
public function getReviewsuservalue(): ?float
{
    return $this->reviewsuservalue;
}

public function setReviewsuservalue(float $reviewsuservalue): self
{
    $this->reviewsuservalue = $reviewsuservalue;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: So, do you have this in you doctrine entity, but not in your DB, right? If so, it won't be showed (nor added) in your db. If your DB does not have that column, Symfony will show an exception and complain about you trying to flush to a column that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use SerializerInterface & AbstractNormalizer;

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractNormalizer;
```

```
     $new_variable = $serializer->normalize($userForeach, null, [
            AbstractNormalizer::ATTRIBUTES => ['id', 'otherAttribute' , ...],
        ]);
    return $new_variable;
```